# Using *ngFor for an array showing error about object

Tags: angular

I am making a call to a postcode to address API. I want to display the list of addresses in my app.

```
public lookupAddresses: any = {};
```

To make my API call I am using:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  

this.http.get('https://api.getAddress.io/v2/uk/nn13er?api-key=my-api-key&format=true', {headers:headers}).map(res => res.json().Addresses).subscribe(data => {
    this.lookupAddresses = data
    console.log(data);
});
```

And then within my template I have:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let address of lookupAddresses">
        {{ address[0] }}
    </ion-item>         
</ion-list>
```

But I get this error ..

```
Error in ./RegisterPage class RegisterPage
caused by: Cannot find a differ supporting object 
'[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports 
binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

If I console.log the value of data then I get this structure.

```
Array[42]
0 : Array[5]
    0 : "10 Watkin Terrace"
    1 : ""
    2 : ""
    3 : "Northampton"
    4 : "Northamptonshire"
    length : 5
1 : Array[5]
    0 : "11 Watkin Terrace"
    1 : ""
    2 : ""
    3 : "Northampton"
    4 : "Northamptonshire"
    length : 5
2 : Array[5]
    0 : "12 Watkin Terrace"
    1 : ""
    2 : ""
    3 : "Northampton"
    4 : "Northamptonshire"
    length : 5      
....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like you said in your answer, changing

```
public lookupAddresses: any = {};
```

to

```
public lookupAddresses: any;
```

fixes the problem. The reason is that you're setting the default value of `lookupAddresses` to an empty object, rather than an array, or leaving it undefined.

Your `*ngFor` tries to loop through the elements of `lookupAddresses`, before your http request returns, but because `{}` isn't an array, the `*ngFor` fails and prints out an error.

If you instead tried the line

```
public lookupAddresses: any = [];
```

it would also work, since `*ngFor` treats an empty array and undefined the same way, by not looping at all.

Comment: Great, thank you for sharing your knowledge. Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why but this fixes the issue:

Changing:

```
public lookupAddresses: any = {};
```

To:

```
public lookupAddresses: any;
```